# Yii model fetch text from field, without duplicating text

Tags: yii

I have a field  -> tags text,

how do i output all entries tags? without duplicates

```
eg:
entry1 -  tags: one, two, three
entry2 -  tags: two, five
```

i want to be able to output all (one, two, three, five) without duplicates

so how do i find this in model/controller and output it to view?

do i use,

```
key::model()->findAll()   ??
```

Comment: i don't think it's an yii problem or even php problem. it's just a simple text join?

Comment: yes you can use findAll to find all data, and then joing tags text into one array with some function(e.g. array_merge+array_unique) and then output it in view

Comment: thanks! thats what i might need, but im bit new to php for that code, can you give me a short example? Like how do i output the findAll as an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in controller in your action you need to put something like this

```
$data = key::model()->findAll();
$all = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $all = array_merge($all, explode(', ',$d->tags));
}
$all = array_unique($all);
$this->render('index', array(
    'data' => $all,
));
```

and in view something like this

```
echo implode(', ',$data);
```

read this: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

and this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller